# How to wrap piped input to stdout in a bash script?

Tags: bash, stdout, pipe, stdin

I want to write a `bash` script that will wrap `piped` input with some text.

Based on Googling and trying to pick from examples. 
Here is what I have so far, that does not work:

```
#!/bin/sh

if readlink /proc/$$/fd/0 | grep -q "^pipe:"; then
    echo "{ "template":{"name":"contact sheet template","root":"root","parameters": ["pages"]},"pages":"
    cat
    echo "}"
fi
```

I am receiving a JSON list from another program as `piped` input and I want to output before and afterwards with the above text before I `pipe` the results to the next program.

```
program_1 | wrapper.sh | program_2 > outputfile
```

But it doesn't output anything.

**Can someone with more `bash` expertise point me in the right direction?**

Comment: What it suppose to be cat ? Where from is the input ?

Comment: Jarrod - could you please provide an example of what you're sending and what you want it output as?

Answer (score 2):

Personally I'll search in this way :

**myscript.sh**

```
echo 'BEFORE' $(cat) 'AFTER'
```

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean your script is reading standard input from a pipe, such as

```
$ other-process | my-script
```

?

Then the commands in your script will simply inherit standard input from the pipe

```
#!/bin/sh

# Output preamble
cat <<EOF
{ "template":{"name":"contact sheet template","root":"root","parameters": ["pages"]},"pages":
EOF

cat   # This reads from standard input inherited from your script

# Output the closing
cat <<EOF
}
EOF
```